# AWS Amplify doesn't show i18n translation on dynamic page in Nextjs (page directory)

Tags: amazon-web-services, next.js, internationalization, aws-amplify, next-i18next

I am trying to use the [next-i18next](https://github.com/i18next/next-i18next) package in a Nextjs project.
In my dynamic pages like: `/blogs/[id]` section, i18n can't translate the page and only shows its key on the server, but it works fine locally.

this is my code for translation in next-i18next:

`export async function getServerSideProps(context) { const { locale, params: { id }} = context; return { props: {...(await serverSideTranslations(locale))}}}`

On the server it only shows JSON keys and I can't see any translation. (Just for dynamic pages)

I guess this problem is due to the use of amplify and we need to have some configuration for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be an issue related to resolving the message/local files, as mentioned in the [README of next-i18next](https://github.com/i18next/next-i18next/blob/6e4e695c0415fe82579ccfce220ef2fd55429de5/README.md#notes) itself:

> Some serverless PaaS may not be able to locate the path of your
> translations and require additional configuration.

Try adding the absolute path of locales by using `path.resolve`, e.g:

*next-i18next.config.js:*

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    i18n: {
      defaultLocale: 'en',
      locales: ['en', 'cs'],
      localePath: path.resolve('./public/locales')
    },
  };
```